# DiagrammeR - how to move labels outside of nodes

Tags: r, orgchart, diagrammer, ggrepel

How can I move labels outside of the circles utilizing R's DiagrammeR package? I don't see anything in the [instruction manual](https://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/graphviz_and_mermaid.html). Here's my code. In my opinion it's not visually appealing to have the labels inside the circles. If I could apply `ggrepel` to `DiagrammeR` that would be ideal, although I doubt this is possible.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph neato {

graph [layout = neato]

node [shape = circle,
      style = filled,
      color = grey,
      label = '']

node [fillcolor = red]
a [label='Amelia Arduino', fixedsize = true]

node [fillcolor = green]
b c d

node [fillcolor = orange]

l [label = 'Larry Lamp', fixedsize = true]

edge [color = grey]
a -> {b c d}
b -> {e f g h i j}
c -> {k l m n o [label = 'Ophelia Oz', fixedsize = true] 
p [label = 'Peter Pete', fixedsize = true]}
d -> {q r s t u v}
}")
```

[image]